# Проблема окно отчета в tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText , помогите сделать консоль в report window

Tags: python, tkinter

Проблема была в том что я хотел сделать из "tk.scrolledtext" репорт окно. Хотелось чтоб все "logger.info" не отображались только в Console и записывалась в логфайл "Autoloader_PSV5000_log.log",но и в Репорт окно.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from future.builtins import int
import logging
from tkinter.tix import Shell
import subprocess, sys 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from distutils import command
import logging
import logging.config
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
from test.test_quopri import QuopriTestCase
from Tools.scripts.fixdiv import report



root= tk.Tk()

root.title("Autoloader_PSV5000")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 615, height = 515, bg = 'gray94', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()


label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Scan please ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(120, 50, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Report window ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(130, 150, window=label2)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root,width=54,bd=5,font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(310, 100, window=entry1)

report1 = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(width=49,height=17,bd=5,state='disabled',font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(250,320,window=report1)


Pass = "| Status : PASSED |"
Fail = "| Status : FAILED |"




def main():
    global Pass
    global Fail
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autoloader_PSV5000")
    print = logger.info
    
    
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')


             
    print(Pass+"Program started")
 
    if os.path.isfile('Autoloader_log.log') :
        print(Pass+"Autoloader_log.log file exist")
    else :
        print(Fail+"Autoloader_log.logile not exist")      
    if os.path.isfile('logging.conf') :
        print(Pass+"Logging.conf file exist")
    else :
        print(Fail+"Logging.conf file not exist")





def CheckSN ():
    global VerificareSN
    global Pass
    global Fail
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autoloader_PSV5000")
    print = logger.info
    VerificareSN = entry1.get()
    if int(len(VerificareSN)) >5 :
        print(Fail+"Inputed value has bad range ! " +"Scanned :" +VerificareSN)
    elif  int(len(VerificareSN)) == 0   :
        print(Fail+"You didn't scan anything ! " +"Scanned :" +VerificareSN)
    else :
        print(Pass+"Imputed value has good range ! " +"Scanned :"+VerificareSN)

def Open ():
    global VerificareSN
    global Pass
    global Fail
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autoloader_PSV5000")
    print = logger.info
    link_proto=("E:\____GEMIS2.0\ENEL_Gemis_2_Leog_Extractor_v3.exe")
    link_single=("C:\Dataio\Tlwin\Trial\single\\tl_single.tsk")
    link_dual=("C:\Dataio\Tlwin\Trial\dual\\tl_dual.tsk")
    try:
        VerificareSN=VerificareSN.lower()
    except NameError:
        print(Fail+"You didn't use button " + "Check")
        return
    else :
        print(Pass+"Was checked with button success  " + "Check" +" Scanned :"+ VerificareSN)
        
    if VerificareSN == "proto" :
        try : 
            subprocess.Popen(link_proto)
        except IOError:
            print (Fail+"Could not open file! Please check : " + link_proto)
        else :
            print (Fail+"File was executed with success : " + link_proto)
    elif VerificareSN == "single" :
        try : 
            subprocess.Popen(link_single)
        except IOError:
            print (Fail+"Could not open file! Please check : " + link_single)
        else :
            print (Pass+"File was executed with success : " + link_single)
    elif VerificareSN == "dual" : 
        try : 
            subprocess.Popen(link_dual)
        except IOError:
            print (Fail+"Could not open file! Please check " + link_dual)
        else :
            print (Pass+"File was executed with success " + link_dual)
    else :
        print(Fail+"Wrong FF routing , no FW assigned for  " +"Scanned :" + VerificareSN)
        
    
    
def Exit ():    
    global Pass
    global Fail
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autoloader_PSV5000")
    print = logger.info
    print(Pass+"Program exit")
    exit(0)
    

def Delete ():
    global Pass
    global Fail
    global VerificareSN
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autodetector")
    print = logger.info
    try:
        VerificareSN=VerificareSN.lower()
    except NameError:
        print(Pass+"Imputed value was deleted ! " )
        entry1.delete(first=0,last=10000)
        return
    else:
        entry1.delete(first=0,last=10000)
        print(Pass+"Imputed value was deleted ! " +"Scanned : " + VerificareSN)

button1 = tk.Button(text='Check', height=1, width=10,command=CheckSN, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
button2 = tk.Button(text='Delete',height=1, width=10,command=Delete ,  bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold')) 
button3 = tk.Button(text='Load FW', height=1, width=10,command=Open,  bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold')) 
button4 = tk.Button(text='Exit', height=1, width=10,command=Exit,  bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold')) 

canvas1.create_window(500, 200, window=button1)
canvas1.create_window(500, 280, window=button2)
canvas1.create_window(500, 360, window=button3)
canvas1.create_window(500, 440, window=button4)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()   


root.mainloop(0)
```

**logging.confg**

```
[loggers]
keys=root,exampleApp
 
[handlers]
keys=fileHandler, consoleHandler
 
[formatters]
keys=myFormatter
 
[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
 
[logger_exampleApp]
level=INFO
handlers=fileHandler
qualname=Autoloader_PSV5000

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=myFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)
 
[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
formatter=myFormatter
args=("Autoloader_PSV5000_log.log",)
 
[formatter_myFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

[image: Так выглядит программа]

Comment: Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: уже получилось :)))

Answer (score 0):

Код после модификацый :##########################################################

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from future.builtins import int
import logging
from tkinter.tix import Shell
import subprocess, sys 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from distutils import command
import logging
import logging.config
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
from test.test_quopri import QuopriTestCase
from Tools.scripts.fixdiv import report



root= tk.Tk()

root.title("Autoloader_PSV5000")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 615, height = 515, bg = 'gray94', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()


label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Scan please ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(120, 50, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Report window ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(130, 150, window=label2)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root,width=54,bd=5,font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(310, 100, window=entry1)

report1 = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(width=49,height=17,bd=5,state='disabled',font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(250,320,window=report1)


Pass = "| Status : PASSED |"
Fail = "| Status : FAILED |"
#######################################Добавлено################################ 
class TextHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, text):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.text = text

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        def append():
            self.text.configure(state='normal')
            self.text.insert(tk.END, msg + '\n')
            self.text.configure(state='disabled')
            self.text.yview(tk.END)
        self.text.after(0, append)

#######################################Добавлено################################ 

def main():
    global Pass
    global Fail
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autoloader_PSV5000")
    print = logger.info
    
    
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
#######################################Добавлено################################   
    text_handler = TextHandler(report1)
    logger = logging.getLogger()        
    logger.addHandler(text_handler) 
#######################################Добавлено################################ 
             
    print(Pass+"Program started")
 
    if os.path.isfile('Autoloader_log.log') :
        print(Pass+"Autoloader_log.log file exist")
    else :
        print(Fail+"Autoloader_log.logile not exist")      
    if os.path.isfile('logging.conf') :
        print(Pass+"Logging.conf file exist")
    else :
        print(Fail+"Logging.conf file not exist")





def CheckSN ():
    global VerificareSN
    global Pass
    global Fail
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autoloader_PSV5000")
    print = logger.info
    VerificareSN = entry1.get()
    if int(len(VerificareSN)) >5 :
        print(Fail+"Inputed value has bad range ! " +"Scanned :" +VerificareSN)
    elif  int(len(VerificareSN)) == 0   :
        print(Fail+"You didn't scan anything ! " +"Scanned :" +VerificareSN)
    else :
        print(Pass+"Imputed value has good range ! " +"Scanned :"+VerificareSN)

def Open ():
    global VerificareSN
    global Pass
    global Fail
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autoloader_PSV5000")
    print = logger.info
    link_proto=("E:\____GEMIS2.0\ENEL_Gemis_2_Leog_Extractor_v3.exe")
    link_single=("C:\Dataio\Tlwin\Trial\single\\tl_single.tsk")
    link_dual=("C:\Dataio\Tlwin\Trial\dual\\tl_dual.tsk")
    try:
        VerificareSN=VerificareSN.lower()
    except NameError:
        print(Fail+"You didn't use button " + "Check")
        return
    else :
        print(Pass+"Was checked with button success  " + "Check" +" Scanned :"+ VerificareSN)
        
    if VerificareSN == "proto" :
        try : 
            subprocess.Popen(link_proto)
        except IOError:
            print (Fail+"Could not open file! Please check : " + link_proto)
        else :
            print (Fail+"File was executed with success : " + link_proto)
    elif VerificareSN == "single" :
        try : 
            subprocess.Popen(link_single)
        except IOError:
            print (Fail+"Could not open file! Please check : " + link_single)
        else :
            print (Pass+"File was executed with success : " + link_single)
    elif VerificareSN == "dual" : 
        try : 
            subprocess.Popen(link_dual)
        except IOError:
            print (Fail+"Could not open file! Please check " + link_dual)
        else :
            print (Pass+"File was executed with success " + link_dual)
    else :
        print(Fail+"Wrong FF routing , no FW assigned for  " +"Scanned :" + VerificareSN)
        
    
    
def Exit ():    
    global Pass
    global Fail
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autoloader_PSV5000")
    print = logger.info
    print(Pass+"Program exit")
    exit(0)
    

def Delete ():
    global Pass
    global Fail
    global VerificareSN
    logger = logging.getLogger("Autodetector")
    print = logger.info
    try:
        VerificareSN=VerificareSN.lower()
    except NameError:
        print(Pass+"Imputed value was deleted ! " )
        entry1.delete(first=0,last=10000)
        return
    else:
        entry1.delete(first=0,last=10000)
        print(Pass+"Imputed value was deleted ! " +"Scanned : " + VerificareSN)

button1 = tk.Button(text='Check', height=1, width=10,command=CheckSN, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
button2 = tk.Button(text='Delete',height=1, width=10,command=Delete ,  bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold')) 
button3 = tk.Button(text='Load FW', height=1, width=10,command=Open,  bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold')) 
button4 = tk.Button(text='Exit', height=1, width=10,command=Exit,  bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold')) 

canvas1.create_window(500, 200, window=button1)
canvas1.create_window(500, 280, window=button2)
canvas1.create_window(500, 360, window=button3)
canvas1.create_window(500, 440, window=button4)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()   


root.mainloop(0)
```

Вот и фото после:
[image: foto]

Чтоб код работал , нужно еще 1 файла (loggin.conf):
Нужно создать фаил "loggin.conf" и копировать код который находится ниже.

```
[loggers]
keys=root,exampleApp
 
[handlers]
keys=fileHandler, consoleHandler
 
[formatters]
keys=myFormatter
 
[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
 
[logger_exampleApp]
level=INFO
handlers=fileHandler
qualname=Autoloader_PSV5000

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=myFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)
 
[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
formatter=myFormatter
args=("Autoloader_PSV5000_log.log",)
 
[formatter_myFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```